# Generating an array of integers with distinct numbers and the first one cannot be zero

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, linq, random

I want to create an array of four integer like this :

1. The cases are distincts
2. each value is between 0 and 9
3. the first must be different of zero

**Examples**

- 2542 ==> not valid ( two cases has the same value)
- 0259 ==> not valid ( the position of zero )
- 1025 ==> valid

I tried this snippet :

```
int[] _current_number = new int[4];
Random randNum = new Random();
_current_number = Enumerable.Repeat(0, 4)
                            .Select(i => randNum.Next(0, 9))
                            .ToArray();
```

How can I improve my code ?

Comment: Your second constraint isn't an actual constraint: every number is between 0 and 9, bounds included.

Comment: Why don't you generate a number between 1000 and 9999 ? Then your generated number will never have a zero at the start and always be 4 digits long.

Comment: @PaulZahra the result of my code isn't exactly what I want , it need some modification

Comment: @LamloumiAfif Then could you be more specific?

Comment: @PaulZahra see the first condition plz

Comment: @LamloumiAfif I think jyparask answer is the one... results in 4536 possible unique numbers, when used with the range (1023,8976)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opion this is the most readable and efficient way:

```
Random r = new Random();
HashSet<int> nums = new HashSet<int>() { r.Next(1, 10) };// add the one with non-zero logic first
while (nums.Count < 4)
    nums.Add(r.Next(0, 10));
int[] result = nums.ToArray();
```

LINQ is not the best tool for this job since you have a different logic according to the index and because you need to check for duplicates constantly. A LINQ query does not "know" it's state until it gets executed. The `HashSet<T>` is perfect for this requirement.

Answer (score 3):

```
Enumerable.Range(1000,8999)
.Where(x=>x.ToString().ToArray().Distinct().Count()==4)
.ToArray();
```

Comment: This will return `IEnumerable` starting from 1023... What's next?

Comment: @KonradKokosa 1000 to 1009 has 0 doubled so it should be eliminated. 1010 to 1019 has 1 doubled so they are eliminated. 1020 has two 0s 1021 has two 1s and 1022 has two 2s so they are eliminated. All these eliminations are per the first rule `2542 ==> not valid ( two cases has the same value)`

Comment: This looks promising but generates numbers over 10,000 ??!?!

Comment: Think your code should be Enumerable.Range(1023,8765) ?

Comment: @PaulZahra You were right. The second argument of the Range method is the count of numbers. Since i am starting from 1000 the last would be 11000. I updated it.

Comment: @PaulZahra Why should i precalculate the maximum number? I would let the code handle that.

Comment: @jyparask see me previous post... the first valid number is 1023 so start there, and the last valid number is 9786 resulting in the last parameter of your range being 8976 I believe.

Comment: @PaulZahra Indeed they are, but why should the coder do the calculation, just to get rid of 50 itterations out of 8.5K?

Answer (score 3):

```
Random rng = new Random();

int[] numbers = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).OrderBy(x => rng.Next()).ToArray();

if (numbers[0] == 0) // If first is 0, swap with another random element.
{
    int i = 1 + rng.Next(9);
    numbers[0] = numbers[i];
    numbers[i] = 0;
}

int[] result = numbers.Take(4).ToArray(); // Use the 4 numbers in result[]
```

This works as follows:

1. Create a sequence of all the numbers between 0 and 9 inclusive.
2. Shuffle those numbers into an array.
3. If the first item in the shuffled numbers is 0, swap it with another random element.
4. Take the first 4 items from the shuffled numbers.

Comment: Ordering needs something stable to sort by. Chances that the first digit ends on the end of the IEnumerable is very low, whilest at the front is very high. I would prefer shuffling, but other than that I like the solution the most. It's very clean.

Comment: What about distinct values `2542 ==> not valid ( two cases has the same value)`

Comment: @Caramiriel That way of shuffling (using OrderBy()) is well-known and works just fine. It's a little slow, but it is a valid way of shuffling. That said, I have a proper shuffle algorithm in a library (implementing Fisher-Yates shuffle) that I use for shuffling, but I didn't want to complicate things by posting it in this answer!

Comment: @LamloumiAfif This code will never produce duplicate numbers in any one result. It definitely works (and I tested it, of course).

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly linq, but another aproach, typed from memory :)

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
Random randNum = new Random();
var rand = randNum.Next(1, 9);
numbers.add(rand);

do
{
  rand = randNum.Next(0, 9);
  if(!numbers.contains(rand))
  {
     numbers.add(rand);
   }
}
while (numbers.Count < 4);
```